# SAP Fiori Company Logo in Fiori-Launchpad

Tags: sap-fiori

I'm using the SAP Fiori Launchpad as Portal. Now my Customer wants to change the default SAP Logo by a Company Logo. I tried this via Transaction UI5/THEME_DESIGNER. This works but can someone tell me which size is recommended for the company logo? It looks ugly and unsharp. Can't find something in the Fiori Designguide.

Comment: Have you tried saving the default SAP logo as an image, then checking which dimensions it has?

Comment: @ChrisNeve Good Idea I will give it a try :-)

Comment: @ChrisNeve works:-)

Answer (score 1):

well, this also depends on the Fiori version you use.

On our current system, the SAP Logo is 55x27.

The current Version of https://www.sapfioritrial.com uses a 50x26 image, but you can use up to 96x36, which is the max-width/max-height on the CSS class holding the image Tag (.sapUshellShellHeadEnd>.sapUshellShellIco>img, .sapUshellShellHeadBegin>.sapUshellShellIco>img).

the max-width/max-height can be changed using Theme Designer as well.

But as long as you are only exchanging the Logo, I would stick to the standard sizing and use a logo of size up to 96x36. Note that if the image file is larger, it may get scaled unproportionally (didnt try though)